# Unable to Connect "IBM.Data.DB2.Core" version "1.3.0.100" from Azure Functions with AzureFunctionsVersion v2

Tags: azure, db2

When I have used `IBM.Data.DB2.Core` version `1.3.0.100` dll to connect DB2 database from Azure functions with `AzureFunctionsVersion V2`. Application build successfully. but run time I am facing below exception.

Azure function target framework is `.Net Core 2.1`. Please provide any suggestion to resolve
[image]

Comment: Do not post images of error messages, instead copy the *text* of the error message into the question.

Comment: Paste the text messages here, and use those buttons on the editor to format it.